# How can i create a button with boolean and a specific id?

Tags: angular, ngfor, codemirror

I am currently coding a component to display documentation, like qt doc (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) and I am using CodeMirror to display a code example.

I am using Angular 2:

```html
<div *ngFor="let method of methods" style="background-color: inherit; margin: left">
      <div class="content" style="position: relative;">

        <p class="title" style="font-size: 150%; text-decoration: underline" id="{{method.id}}">
          {{ method?.name }}
        </p>
        <br/>
        <p class="description" *ngIf="method"  [innerHtml]="method.description | textToHtml"></p>
        <div class="markdown" markdownMethodDocumentationRenderer [text]="method.documentation"></div>
        <button class="button" *ngIf="!showCode" (click)="showCloseExample()">Show example</button>
        <button class="button" *ngIf="showCode" (click)="showCloseExample()">Close example</button>
        <div *ngIf="showCode">
          <app-code-mirror [data]="method.documentation"></app-code-mirror>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <hr>
        <br/>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I created a button to show or hide a div with a CodeMirror component inside but when I click this button, it opens every examples.
I think it's because it's on an `ngFor`.
When I click this button, I want to open only one div and not all.

Comment: Post something as code snippet to give us an idea what exactly your problem is

Comment: Could you please provide more code? Not much can be done using only one line you provided

Comment: y it's my first post, i had difficulty to copy past

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are changing one variable **showCode**. You are also watching that **showCode** variable, and opening/closing each of your snippets whenever it changes.

There are many solutions for this problem, one of them being as follows:

Add a new boolean in each object of your *methods* array. Lets call it **showCode**, as  you did. Now each method has a showCode flag. Instead of `ngIf="showCode"`, you will have `ngIf="method.showCode"`.

Now, instead of `(click)="showCloseExample()"`, you can do something like `(click)="method.showCode = !method.showCode"`. (I believe this is the right syntax in Angular, if not, bind it to a function and pass the index of the method, and then update methods showCode flag)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to either use array of `showCode` flags or add flag to method variable. Right now you are using single flag `showCode` to show/hide every element in `*ngFor`.

Comment: So, i have to create an array of booleans associated with every method of my array methodS ??

Comment: Yes, and use apropriate flag in required `ngFor` iteration. Thats one way to do it.